# Example of apple maps url to find the directions to certain coordinates

Tags: ios, maps, apple-maps

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

I'd like to create a url which will open the maps app on iphones and make it show the directions from the user's current location to the certain coordinates.
Could you show an example of such url?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use latitude and longitude values separated by a comma as the destination address:

http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=37.331778,-122.031375

Comment: tell me please how i can add zoom level?

Comment: @Igor+Zinchenko see details at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html  
To add zoom level, add "?z=5.0" where you can change the "5.0" to a zoom value between 1 and 21.  *However*, you can only add the "?z" when you are using the "ll" parameter which takes the latitude and longitude values of the location you want to show on the map.